# AC MCB or DC MCB

Tags: switches, battery-charging, power-electronics

I'm using MCBs on one of my projects involving a battery pack. Is it safe to connect using an AC MCB (Brand Legrand India) for switching between the states (on/off)?

Vbat < 100 V, expected current < 40 A.

Comment: If you are switching DC, you must use an MCB that's rated for DC (and in the case of an MCB that supports both, you *must* follow the DC specific ratings). In particular, DC is "harder" for a circuit breaker to safely interrupt. If you want us to review a particular MCB, we need to see the datasheet and/or specification and not just the brand name.

Comment: 100 V is way above what run-off-the-mill AC MCBs will handle. You need a DC rated one.